# A tool to generate and verify signature of a binary file

Tags: signature

I'm looking for an easy to use tool to generate RsaPssSha256 digital signature of a binary file using the private key. and verify the signature using the modulus and exponent of the public key.

any suggestion?

Comment: RSA sign, DSA, ECDSA, edDSA, however, what is the type of your private key?

Comment: @kelalaka updated the question

Comment: Then what do you want, a library?

Comment: There is [software recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). did you look at OpenSLL. It has a long tradition about cryptography...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430091/589259